# Agrupar por coincidencias en un array PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array multidimensional con índices, en el cual guardo los datos, sobre un usuario y sus paradas, esto lo muestro por días. Me interesa que los días que tengan las mismas paradas queden agrupados.

El array lo consigo de dos consultas *SQL* de esta forma:

```
$resultado = listado1($alumnos,$etapas,$clases,$grupos,$ano,$filtroUsuarios,$filtroEtapas,$filtroClase,$filtroGrupo);//Primera consulta
$arrParadasPorDia = Array();
//En el primer for agrupo las paradas que tiene un dia
for($i=0;$i<count($resultado);$i++){//Recojo los valores de la primera consulta y los voy guardando en un nuevo array (Para unirlo con la otra consulta)
    $tmp = Array(); 
    $tmp["ANO"] = $resultado[$i]["ANO"];//AÑO
    $tmp["NOMBRE"] = $resultado[$i]["NOMBRE"];//NOMBRE USUARIO
    $tmp["CODUSU"] = $resultado[$i]["CODUSU"];//CODIGO USUARIO
    $tmp["ENCARGADO"] = $resultado[$i]["ENCARGADO"];//ENCARGADO DEL USUARIO
    $tmp["TLFNO"] = $resultado[$i]["TLFNO"];//TELEFONO DEL USUARIO
    $tmp["DIASEMANA"] = $resultado[$i]["DIASEMANA"];//DIA DE LA SEMANA
    $paradas = Array(); //Creo un nuevo array para guardar los valores de la segunda consulta
    $resultado2 = listado2($resultado[$i]["TSRVDSE"],$resultado[$i]["USCOD"]); //Ejecuto la segunda consulta que tiene como filtros valores de la primera de ellas
    for($j=0;$j<count($resultado2);$j++){   //Recorro la segunda consulta
        $tmp2 = Array();
        $tmp2["HORA"] = $resultado2[$j]["HORA"];//HORA
        $tmp2["PARADA"] = $resultado2[$j]["PARADA"];//PARADA
        $tmp2["CALLE"] = $resultado2[$j]["CALLE"];//CALLE
        array_push($paradas,$tmp2);
    }
    $tmp["PARADAS"] = $paradas;//AÑADO EL ARRAY DE LA SEGUNDA CONSULTA A UN "INDICE" DEL PRIMER ARRAY
    array_push($arrParadasPorDia,$tmp);//GUARDO EL RESULTADO EL EN ARRAY PRIMARIO   
}
```

Una vez echo esto tengo los datos guardados de manera correcta, puedo ver los resultados de esta manera:

```
foreach($arrParadasPorDia as $resultado){
    echo "AÑO ".$resultado["ANO"]."<br/>";
    echo "NOMBRE ".$resultado["NOMBRE"]."<br/>";
    echo "USUARIO ".$resultado["CODUSU"]."<br/>";
    echo "TUTOR ".$resultado["ENCARGADO"]."<br/>";
    echo "TLFNO ".$resultado["TLFNO"]."<br/>";
    echo "DIA SEMANA ".$resultado["DIASEMANA"]."<br/>";
    $i = 0;     
    foreach($resultado["PARADAS"] as $paradas){
        $i++;
        echo "PARADA".$i.": ";
        echo "DIRECION ".$paradas["TSRVDIR"]."<br/>";
        echo "HORA ".$paradas["HORA"]."<br/>";
        echo "PARADA ".$paradas["PARADA"]."<br/>";
        echo "CALLE".$paradas["CALLE"]."<br/>";
    }
    echo "<hr/>";
}
```

Los resultados que muestro son algo así:

```
AÑO 2016
NOMBRE ANDONI ALDA
USUARIO 000001
ENCARGADO ANDONI ALDA
TLFNO 666000666
DIA SEMANA 1
PARADA1:
HORA 855
PARADA 1
CALLE C/MAYOR

PARADA2:
HORA 1040
PARADA 1
CALLE C/MENOR

AÑO 2016
NOMBRE ANDONI ALDA
USUARIO 000001
ENCARGADO ANDONI ALDA
TLFNO 666000666
DIA SEMANA 2
PARADA1:
HORA 855
PARADA 1
CALLE C/MAYOR

PARADA2:
HORA 1040
PARADA 1
CALLE C/MENOR

AÑO 2016
NOMBRE ANDONI ALDA
USUARIO 000001
ENCARGADO ANDONI ALDA
TLFNO 666000666
DIA SEMANA 3
PARADA1:
HORA 855
PARADA 1
CALLE C/MAYOR

PARADA2:
HORA 1040
PARADA 1
CALLE C/MENOR

AÑO 2016
NOMBRE ANDONI ALDA
USUARIO 000001
ENCARGADO ANDONI ALDA
TLFNO 666000666
DIA SEMANA 4
PARADA1:
HORA 855
PARADA 1
CALLE C/MAYOR

PARADA2:
HORA 1040
PARADA 1
CALLE C/MENOR

AÑO 2016
NOMBRE ANDONI ALDA
USUARIO 000001
ENCARGADO ANDONI ALDA
TLFNO 666000666
DIA SEMANA 5
PARADA1:
HORA 855
PARADA 1
CALLE C/PUERTOURRACO

PARADA2:
HORA 1040
PARADA 1
CALLE Avenida de la playa
```

Como veis los días 1, 2, 3 y 4 tienen las mismas paradas a la misma hora y el día 5 tiene las paradas a la misma hora pero a un lugar distinto.

Me interesaria que los datos se mostraran de la siguiente forma:

```
AÑO 2016
NOMBRE ANDONI ALDA
USUARIO 000001
ENCARGADO ANDONI ALDA
TLFNO 666000666
DIA SEMANA 1,2,3,4
PARADA1:
HORA 855
PARADA 1
CALLE C/MAYOR

PARADA2:
HORA 1040
PARADA 1
CALLE C/MENOR


AÑO 2016
NOMBRE ANDONI ALDA
USUARIO 000001
ENCARGADO ANDONI ALDA
TLFNO 666000666
DIA SEMANA 5
PARADA1:
HORA 855
PARADA 1
CALLE C/PUERTOURRACO

PARADA2:
HORA 1040
PARADA 1
CALLE Avenida de la playa
```

Y no solo mostrarlos, si es posible guardarlos en un array.

He conseguido agrupar de esta manera:

```
$arrFinal = Array();
$primera = true;
$dias = "";
for($i=0;$i<count($arrParadasPorDia);$i++){
    if($i == 0){//Si es la primera vez que pasa se almacenan los datos en un array temporal         
        $tmp = Array();
        $tmp["ANO"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["ANO"];
        $tmp["NOMBRE"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["NOMBRE"];
        $tmp["CODUSU"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["CODUSU"];
        $tmp["ENCARGADO"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["ENCARGADO"];
        $tmp["TLFNO"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["TLFNO"];
        $dias = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["DIASEMANA"]; //Variable que recojera los dias iguales.
        $tmp["PARADAS"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["PARADAS"];
    }else{
    if($arrParadasPorDia[$i]["PARADAS"] == $arrParadasPorDia[$i-1]["PARADAS"]){//Si la las paradas son iguales a las del dia anterior se almacena el dia en la variable dias
        $dias = $dias.", ".$arrParadasPorDia[$i]["DIASEMANA"];
    }else{//Si son distintos
        $tmp["DIAS"] = $dias;//Guardo la variable dias en el array temporal
        array_push($arrFinal,$tmp);//Añado el array temporal al definitivo
        $tmp = Array();//Vacio el array y le añado los datos del dia que es distinto
        $tmp["ANO"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["ANO"];
        $tmp["NOMBRE"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["NOMBRE"];
        $tmp["CODUSU"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["CODUSU"];
        $tmp["ENCARGADO"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["ENCARGADO"];
        $tmp["TLFNO"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["TLFNO"];
        $dias = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["DIASEMANA"];
        $tmp["PARADAS"] = $arrParadasPorDia[$i]["PARADAS"];
        }
    }
}
$tmp["DIAS"] = $dias;//El ultimo dia no se guarda en el array porque sale del for antes de guardar por lo que hay que hacer esto.
array_push($arrFinal,$tmp);
```

Esto podría ser una solución pero tiene un problema, por ejemplo, si el dia 1, 2 y 4 son iguales y el 3 y el 5 distintos, debería mostrar 3 resultados, uno para los dia 1, 2 y 4, otro para el dia 3 y otro para el 5, pero con este método muestro 4 resultados. Uno para el dia 1 y 2 otro para el dia 3 otro para el 4 y un último para el dia 5, por lo que esta solución es válida, pero no es la que busco.

Por petición de @OscarGarcia y de @Mariano dejo los datos resultantes de `var_export($arrParadasPorDia)`para trabajar con ellos:

```
array ( 0 => array 
    ( 'ANO' => 2016,    
        'NOMBRE' => 'ANDONI ALDA', 
        'USCOD' => '000001',    
        'ENCARGADO' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
        'USRTELEFONO' => 685358487,      
        'DIASEMANA' => 1,
        'PARADAS' =>
        array ( 0 => array 
            ('HORA' => 855,
            'PARADA' => 1,
            'CALLE' => 'C/MAYOR',
            ),
            1 => array 
            ( 'HORA' => 1040,
            'PARADA' => 1,
            'CALLE' => 'C/MENOR',
            ),
        ),
    ), 
     1 => array 
        ( 'ANO' => 2016,    
        'NOMBRE' => 'ANDONI ALDA', 
        'USCOD' => '000001',    
        'ENCARGADO' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
        'USRTELEFONO' => 685358487,      
        'DIASEMANA' => 2,
        'PARADAS' =>
        array ( 0 => array 
            ('HORA' => 855,
            'PARADA' => 1,
            'CALLE' => 'C/MAYOR',
            ),
            1 => array 
            ( 'HORA' => 1040,
            'PARADA' => 1,
            'CALLE' => 'C/MENOR',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    2 => array 
        ( 'ANO' => 2016,    
        'NOMBRE' => 'ANDONI ALDA', 
        'USCOD' => '000001',    
        'ENCARGADO' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
        'USRTELEFONO' => 685358487,      
        'DIASEMANA' => 3,
        'PARADAS' =>
        array ( 0 => array 
            ('HORA' => 855,
            'PARADA' => 1,
            'CALLE' => 'C/MAYOR',
            ),
            1 => array 
            ( 'HORA' => 1040,
            'PARADA' => 1,
            'CALLE' => 'C/MENOR',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    3 => array 
        ( 'ANO' => 2016,    
        'NOMBRE' => 'ANDONI ALDA', 
        'USCOD' => '000001',    
        'ENCARGADO' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
        'USRTELEFONO' => 685358487,      
        'DIASEMANA' => 4,
        'PARADAS' =>
        array ( 0 => array 
            ('HORA' => 855,
            'PARADA' => 1,
            'CALLE' => 'C/MAYOR',
            ),
            1 => array 
            ( 'HORA' => 1040,
            'PARADA' => 1,
            'CALLE' => 'C/MENOR',
            ),
        ),
    ), 
    4 => array 
        ( 'ANO' => 2016,    
        'NOMBRE' => 'ANDONI ALDA', 
        'USCOD' => '000001',    
        'ENCARGADO' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
        'USRTELEFONO' => 685358487,      
        'DIASEMANA' => 5,
        'PARADAS' =>
        array ( 0 => array 
            ('HORA' => 855,
            'PARADA' => 1,
            'CALLE' => 'CALLE C/PUERTOURRACO',
            ),
            1 => array 
            ( 'HORA' => 1040,
            'PARADA' => 1,
            'CALLE' => 'Avenida de la playa',
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58888/discussion-on-question-by-andoni-alda-agrupar-por-coincidencias-en-un-array-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He desarrollado este bucle que realiza la función que deseas (más abajo explico su funcionamiento):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$datos = array (
 0 => array
    ( 'ANO' => 2016,
    'NOMBRE' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
    'USCOD' => '000001',
    'ENCARGADO' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
    'USRTELEFONO' => 685358487,
    'DIASEMANA' => 1,
    'PARADAS' =>
    array ( 0 => array
        ('HORA' => 855,
        'PARADA' => 1,
        'CALLE' => 'C/MAYOR',
        ),
        1 => array
        ( 'HORA' => 1040,
        'PARADA' => 1,
        'CALLE' => 'C/MENOR',
        ),
    ),
),
 1 => array
    ( 'ANO' => 2016,
    'NOMBRE' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
    'USCOD' => '000001',
    'ENCARGADO' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
    'USRTELEFONO' => 685358487,
    'DIASEMANA' => 2,
    'PARADAS' =>
    array ( 0 => array
        ('HORA' => 855,
        'PARADA' => 1,
        'CALLE' => 'C/MAYOR',
        ),
        1 => array
        ( 'HORA' => 1040,
        'PARADA' => 1,
        'CALLE' => 'C/MENOR',
        ),
    ),
),

2 => array
    ( 'ANO' => 2016,
    'NOMBRE' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
    'USCOD' => '000001',
    'ENCARGADO' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
    'USRTELEFONO' => 685358487,
    'DIASEMANA' => 3,
    'PARADAS' =>
    array ( 0 => array
        ('HORA' => 855,
        'PARADA' => 1,
        'CALLE' => 'C/MAYOR',
        ),
        1 => array
        ( 'HORA' => 1040,
        'PARADA' => 1,
        'CALLE' => 'C/MENOR',
        ),
    ),
),
3 => array
    ( 'ANO' => 2016,
    'NOMBRE' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
    'USCOD' => '000001',
    'ENCARGADO' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
    'USRTELEFONO' => 685358487,
    'DIASEMANA' => 4,
    'PARADAS' =>
    array ( 0 => array
        ('HORA' => 855,
        'PARADA' => 1,
        'CALLE' => 'C/MAYOR',
        ),
        1 => array
        ( 'HORA' => 1040,
        'PARADA' => 1,
        'CALLE' => 'C/MENOR',
        ),
    ),
),
4 => array
    ( 'ANO' => 2016,
    'NOMBRE' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
    'USCOD' => '000001',
    'ENCARGADO' => 'ANDONI ALDA',
    'USRTELEFONO' => 685358487,
    'DIASEMANA' => 5,
    'PARADAS' =>
    array ( 0 => array
        ('HORA' => 855,
        'PARADA' => 1,
        'CALLE' => 'CALLE C/PUERTOURRACO',
        ),
        1 => array
        ( 'HORA' => 1040,
        'PARADA' => 1,
        'CALLE' => 'Avenida de la playa',
        ),
    ),
));
$resultado = [];
foreach($datos as $dato) {
    if (!isset($resultado[$dato['USCOD']])) {
        $resultado[$dato['USCOD']] = $dato;
        unset(
          $resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['DIASEMANA'],
          $resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['PARADAS']
        );
        $resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['RUTAS'] = [];
    }
    $clave = [];
    foreach($dato['PARADAS'] as $parada) {
        array_push($clave, $parada['HORA'], $parada['CALLE']);
    }
    $clave = implode(':', $clave);
    if (!isset($resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['RUTAS'][$clave])) {
        $resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['RUTAS'][$clave] = [
            'DIAS' => [],
            'PARADAS' => $dato['PARADAS'],
        ];
    }
    array_push($resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['RUTAS'][$clave]['DIAS'], $dato['DIASEMANA']);
}

foreach($resultado as $clave => $valor) {
  $resultado[$clave]['RUTAS'] = array_values($valor['RUTAS']);
}
$resultado = array_values($resultado);
echo json_encode($resultado, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

El resultado mostrado es:

```
[
  {
    "ANO": 2016,
    "NOMBRE": "ANDONI ALDA",
    "USCOD": "000001",
    "ENCARGADO": "ANDONI ALDA",
    "USRTELEFONO": 685358487,
    "RUTAS": [
      {
        "DIAS": [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4
        ],
        "PARADAS": [
          {
            "HORA": 855,
            "PARADA": 1,
            "CALLE": "C\/MAYOR"
          },
          {
            "HORA": 1040,
            "PARADA": 1,
            "CALLE": "C\/MENOR"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "DIAS": [
          5
        ],
        "PARADAS": [
          {
            "HORA": 855,
            "PARADA": 1,
            "CALLE": "CALLE C\/PUERTOURRACO"
          },
          {
            "HORA": 1040,
            "PARADA": 1,
            "CALLE": "Avenida de la playa"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

**Cómo funciona**

Bucle principal en el que comprobamos si existe un usuario (buscando por su clave primaria, usada como índice en la matriz, agregando los datos a ella conforme se necesiten:

```
$resultado = [];
foreach($datos as $dato) {
    if (!isset($resultado[$dato['USCOD']])) {
        $resultado[$dato['USCOD']] = $dato;
        unset(
          $resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['DIASEMANA'],
          $resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['PARADAS']
        );
        $resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['RUTAS'] = [];
    }
```

En este bucle generamos un índice para la matriz de rutas que será único por cada recorrido (concatenación secuencial de hora/dirección):

```
    $clave = [];
    foreach($dato['PARADAS'] as $parada) {
        array_push($clave, $parada['HORA'], $parada['CALLE']);
    }
    $clave = implode(':', $clave);
```

Si la ruta no existe generamos los datos iniciales:

```
    if (!isset($resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['RUTAS'][$clave])) {
        $resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['RUTAS'][$clave] = [
            'DIAS' => [],
            'PARADAS' => $dato['PARADAS'],
        ];
    }
```

Agregamos el día a la ruta:

```
    array_push($resultado[$dato['USCOD']]['RUTAS'][$clave]['DIAS'], $dato['DIASEMANA']);
```

Finalizamos el bucle principal:

```
}
```

Limpiamos los índices que hemos usado para gestionar la repetición de rutas de un usuario y el usuario mismo:

```
foreach($resultado as $clave => $valor) {
  $resultado[$clave]['RUTAS'] = array_values($valor['RUTAS']);
}
$resultado = array_values($resultado);
```

Comment: Vaya trabajo te mandaste!!! ... Lo comenté en el chat, comento nuevamente para dejar registro: esto es para el caso de manipular el array, pero viendo que los datos vienen de una base, recomendaría agruparlos en la consulta, recibiéndolos así directamente como resultado del query (más rápido, sencillo, menos datos transferidos)

Comment: Gracias! Yo opino lo mismo. En el mismo bucle de obtención de registros (con una consulta que uniera los datos de las diferentes tablas) se podría haber implementado todo esto ahorrando memoria, consultas SQL, etc..