# ¿Se puede usara array_unique excectuando un valor del array?

Tags: php, array

Existe la posibilidad de que `array_unique` coja los elementos que uno desee de un array, por ejemplo, tenemos un array con claves y nombres, y queremos que se eliminen los nombres duplicados ignorando las claves que pueden ser distintas.

<sub>Se que no tiene sentido hacer esto pero no se me ocurría otro ejemplo</sub>

Es decir que si tenemos un array con estos datos

```
1000 Mortadelo Garcia
1001 Filemon Fernandez
1002 Eduardo ManosTijeras
1003 Filemon Fernandez
```

Si usariamos `array_unique` con estos datos nos devolvería el mismo array ya que el id cambia, pero si se ignoraría la id quedaría este array

```
1000 Mortadelo Garcia
1001 Filemon Fernandez
1002 Eduardo ManosTijeras
```

Incluso me interesa la posibilidad de que se pueda hacer esto:

```
1000 Mortadelo Garcia
1001,1003 Filemon Fernandez
1002 Eduardo ManosTijeras
```

A lo mejor `array_unique` no tiene estas posibilidades y simplemente compara todos los datos del array. Por lo que me surge la siguiente pregunta, como se podría hacer estas comparaciones.

Comment: ¿Esas duplas son índice, valor? `[ 1000 => 'Mortadelo', ... ]`, ¿cierto?

Comment: @OscarGarcia No, lo siento no lo he dejado claro, son las dos valores: seria asi `[id =>'1000',nombre =>'Mortadelo'],...`

Comment: Ahh, vale, entonces modifico mi código. Entonces, ¿cómo quieres el resultado cuando hay varios ids que tienen los mismos datos? ¿En un array de ids o una cadena separada por comas?

Comment: @OscarGarcia ambas soluciones me parecen validas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) no soporta la funcionalidad que deseas, pero puedes implementarla fácilmente:

```
<pre><?php
$datos = [
    1000 => 'Mortadelo Garcia',
    1001 => 'Filemon Fernandez',
    1002 => 'Eduardo ManosTijeras',
    1003 => 'Filemon Fernandez',
];

function array_unicos($array) {
    $resultado = [];
    foreach(array_unique($array) as $elemento) {
        $claves = array_keys($array, $elemento);
        $resultado[implode(',', $claves)] = $elemento;
    }
    return $resultado;
}

var_export(array_unique($datos));
?></pre>
<pre><?php
var_export(array_unicos($datos));
?></pre>
```

El resultado sería:

```
array (
  1000 => 'Mortadelo Garcia',
  1001 => 'Filemon Fernandez',
  1002 => 'Eduardo ManosTijeras',
)
array (
  1000 => 'Mortadelo Garcia',
  '1001,1003' => 'Filemon Fernandez',
  1002 => 'Eduardo ManosTijeras',
)
```

Ten en cuenta que al encontrar varias coincidencias el índice debe convertirse a texto para poder contener los índices originales separados por comas.

Comment: Interesante solución me gustaría saber como puede implementarla en otra pregunta mía, que es para lo que queria saber esto.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70630/agrupar-por-coincidencias-en-un-array-php?noredirect=1#comment129327_70630

Comment: Ya esta, habia pulsado intro antes de tiempo ajaja

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Este método lo que hace es mostrar el número de veces que se encuentra un valor es un array, por ejemplo en el caso que yo he puesto saldría esto:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

No es exactamente lo que pides, pero no creo que haya ningún modo en php capaz de hacer eso, adjunto [doc](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.array.php) con todos los métodos para arrays.